# WP E-commerce: Showing 3 random products from current category when viewing product

Tags: php, e-commerce, plugins

This is more of a template tag question than a programming question, but since WPEC's wiki and forum is quite useless I had to give it a shot here.

Using shortcodes you can easily include a given number of products from a given category in any post and page.

**But how can I achieve the following:**

In the bottom of the single product view template I would like to show three random products from the same category as the product that is being viewed.

> *PS: I'm aware of the related product plugins that exists, but they're
>   struggling with the new product variations in WPEC. That's why I
>   prefer to use the standard category listing included in WPEC instead.*

Thanks in advance for all kinds of help!

Comment: Check this out ->http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/random-posts-from-category/

Comment: This is a *user support*, Plugin-specific question that would be better-directed to the [WP e-Commerce Plugin support forum](http://wordpress.org/tags/wp-e-commerce?forum_id=10).

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your wpsc-single_product.php template.  It will give you a list with title and link.  I didn't test this with product variations, I am not using them in the site I am working with and I wasn't sure from your question if you needed it to.  Hopefully this at least gives you a starting place.

```
<?php 
// get the product categories
$product_categories = wp_get_object_terms( wpsc_the_product_id(), 'wpsc_product_category', array('fields' => 'ids') );
// arguments
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'wpsc-product',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'orderby' => 'rand',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'wpsc_product_category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $product_categories
    )
)
);
$related_products = new WP_Query( $args );
// loop over query
if ($related_products->have_posts()) :
echo '<ul>';
while ( $related_products->have_posts() ) : $related_products->the_post();
?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php
endwhile;
echo '</ul>';
endif;
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current category by:

`<?php get_the_category( $id ) ?>` - Here id is id of your current post.

Than-after use  [`Random Post from Category`](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/random-posts-from-category/) plugin

And give the current category id to it.

And here you will get all products of the current product category.